# How to access / update property of nested fields with MVEL in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, mvel

I want to append some data to a document in Elasticsearch and set a timestamp using MVEL.

this is what I am currently trying. But it does not work.

> {"error":"ElasticSearchIllegalArgumentException[failed to execute
>   script]; nested: PropertyAccessException[[Error: could not access
>   property (Timestamp) in: java.lang.Long]\n[Near : {... Timestamp
>   ....}]\n             ^\n[Line: 1, Column: 1]]; ","status":400}

How can I access the Timestamp field (it is successfully created via a mapping)

```
  {
  "script": "
            valueSet.Timestamp = time();
            if (ctx._source[\"values\"] == null) { ctx._source.values = valueSet} else {ctx._source.values += valueSet}
            ",
  "params": {
    "valueSet": 
    [ 
    {
      "Timestamp": "",
      "value": "100.00"
    } 
   ]
  }
}
```

UPDATE:

Found out how to access the valueSet

```
  {
  "script": "
            valueSet[0].value = 'test';
            if (ctx._source[\"values\"] == null) { ctx._source.values = valueSet} else {ctx._source.values += valueSet}
            ",
  "params": {
    "valueSet": 
    [ 
    {
      "Timestamp": "",
      "value": "100.00"
    } 
   ]
  }
}
```

The above will override the "100.00" to "test".

Comment: Have you tried accessing another field with that script? Maybe the timestamp field is a speacial case?

Comment: japp! no success. it can't access any field from "valueSet" using the above syntax..

Answer (score 1):

I am able to update whole array or whole field very simply just like array.
follow these step.

**step -1** put a smaple data.

```
    PUT /1/user/1
    {
        "userId":2,
        "sid":1,
             "1": [
                    "24 hrs left!"
                ]
            ,
            "2": 9
            ,
             "32": "2014-08-01T00:00:00"
            ,
             "evant": [

        {
            "name": "2",
            "count": 9,
            "first_date":"2014-08-01T00:00:00",
            "last_date":"2014-08-01T00:00:00",
            "_date":["2014-08-01T00:00:00",
            "2014-08-01T00:00:00",
            "2014-08-01T00:00:00"]
        },
        {
            "name": "3",
            "count": 9,
            "first_date":"2014-08-01T00:00:00",
            "last_date":"2014-08-01T00:00:00",
            "_date":["2014-08-01T00:00:00",
            "2014-08-01T00:00:00",
            "2014-08-01T00:00:00"]
        }]
}
```

**step-2**. update any nested filed value.

```
POST  /1/user/1/_update
{
  "script": "foreach (item : ctx._source.evant) { if (item['name'] == name) { item['name'] =  item['name']==null?\"none\": 'myname'; } }",
  "params": {"name": "abc"}
}
```

**step-3**. add any new field.

```
POST  /1/user/1/_update
{
  "script": "foreach (item : ctx._source.evant) { if (item['name'] == name) { item['Fname']='zyz'; } }",
  "params": {"name": "abc"}
}
```